# Batch file to copy SQL backups

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

I'm trying to copy SQL backups from Server1 to Server2 using below batch file. I was able to schedule the backups for the most recent full SQL backup using below script until it stopped working 4 days ago. Can somebody give me a hand on this? Am I missing something in the script?

```
@Echo Off

Rem - Backup files to Server2

    Echo.
    Echo    Backing up full UsersDb backup to Server2
    For %%A in (C:\Backups-All\Backup\7AM\UsersDb_FULL_????201?_??1*.bak) do Set DBBackup=%%A

XCopy %DBBackup% \\Server2\Backup\UsersDbBackup\7AM\*.* /D


Rem - Exit shell
    Echo.
    Echo    Exiting!
    exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Robocopy and www.ss64.com are your friend.

```
@Echo Off
Rem - Backup files to Server2
robocopy C:\Backups-All\Backup\7AM\ \\Server2\Backup\UsersDbBackup\7AM\ /COPYALL /ZB /R:10 /W:10
```